# Qunit testing an Ember.js app with ember-simple-auth authentication?

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, qunit, teaspoon

So, Am writing a Qunit test (with teaspoon as the test runner), for an Ember application that uses ember-simple-auth gem for login authintication, My test is as follows (coffee script) :

```
#=  require qunit_spec_helper

test "Employee signs in", ->
  expect(1)
  visit("/login").then(->
    fillIn "input.email", "employee1@example.com"
  ).then(->
    fillIn "input.user_password", "password1"
  ).then(->
    click "button.btn-primary"
  ).andThen ->
   equal(find('h2').length,1, "Welcome to the App")
```

And here is the Test helper:

```
QUnit.testStart ->

  Ember.run ->
    App.reset()

  Ember.testing = true
    App.setupForTesting()
    App.injectTestHelpers()

QUnit.testDone ->
  Ember.testing = false

QUnit.done ->
  Ember.run ->
    App.reset()
```

When I run the test (keeping any eye on the console), I get the following error:

`POST http://localhost:3000/teaspoon/qunit/oauth/token 404 (Not Found)`

I can't seem to be able to login, No matter what ..
I ran out of ideas, Any help/Advice is highly Appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Ember.SimpleAuth makes a request against the server to authenticate the session when the button is clicked - the route isn't handled by your server though (or the server isn't running at all maybe?) I'd stub the token endpoint for testing, find an example e.g. here: https://github.com/digitalplaywright/eak-simple-auth/blob/master/tests/acceptance/login-test.js

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Is that possible without using sinon ?

Comment: There are other request stubbing libraries as well of course. Or you stub the requests manually (which I wouldn't recommend).

Comment: I was struggling with this. Thanks @marcoow. You're really great about supporting `ember-simple-auth`; keep up the great work!